# how to show opened files in tabs in Gogland IDE?

Tags: go, goland

I'm new to Go lang, and downloaded a IDE named Gogland-EAP.
 (https://download.jetbrains.8686c.com/go/gogland-171.4694.61.dmg)

It's very good, but I don't know how to show opened files in tabs, such as other IDE.

I can only see one opened file at a time, there's no tab at all. After another file opened, the first opened file disappeared.

Is there any special setting for Gogland-EAP I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Editor Tabs**

In section **Tab Appearance** find **Placement** drop down list.

If is it set to **None** then change it to **Top**.

Confirm with **OK** button

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't know why set None as default setting for Placement...